# Definir en Layout Tamaño WebView

Tags: android, android-layout

¿Cómo puedo definir en mi xml el tamaño de un web view? Mi app debe mostrar un sitio en el webview pero éste no debe de ocupar todo el alto de la pantalla, dado que se debe de agregar un control de MediaPlayer. No deseo definirlo en px porque evidentemente los tamaños de las pantallas son variados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que conserve siempre un porcentaje de la medida de la pantalla, la opción es definir la propiedad `layout_weight` en tu vista, suponiendo el siguiente ejemplo, en el cual necesitamos que nuestro `WebView` siempre ocupe un 50% de la pantalla y este posicionado en la parte inferior, pero también necesitamos agregar otras 2 vistas, las cuales una ocupe el 30% de la pantalla y la segunda el 20%.

Si tomamos en cuenta el total de la pantalla como el 1 , asignamos un valor de .50 para que siempre ocupe el 50% de la pantalla nuestro `WebView` :

```
   <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

y asi con las demás vistas, una ocupara el 30% (asignamos .30)  y la otra el 20% (asignamos .20):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:text="Vista 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:text="Vista 2" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Podemos asegurar que las vistas siempre medirán el porcentaje especificado en la pantalla, importante definir `android:layout_height="0dp"`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otro ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:text="Vista 2"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Elenasys, pero al trabajar con px me provocará problemas por los tamaños variados de las pantallas?

Comment: Edite la respuesta, en ese caso es mejor usar dps!

Comment: con dp y px me sucede lo mismo.

Comment: Elensasys lo puse en mi código, el diseño me lo muestra bien, pero al momento de ejecutar la app me muestra el webview al 100% de la pantalla. Si quito la funcion que carga el webview evidentemente no aparece la web en pantalla, pero si el boton.

Comment: podrías agregar tu código por favor-

Comment: Si Elenasys,    
https://github.com/RadioCooperativa/AndroidApp

Comment: La solución funciona correctamente, lo que sucede es que estas creando un nuevo webView (Elimina esta linea: myWebView = new WebView(this);) debes acceder a la referencia del webview que tienes en el layout(Agrega esta línea: myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView); )  y por último tratas de cargar una nueva vista! ( Elimina esta línea : setContentView(myWebView); ).

Comment: Muchas Gracias Elenasys, efectivamente ese era el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Al utilizar un LinearLayout puedes hacer uso del atributo weight. (http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Capaz que eso te permite, estableciendo diferentes pesos a al webview y al control aprovechar la pantalla para el contenido sin perder de vista del control.

(Otro vinculo a la explicación pero en castellano, no es mía pero ayuda entiendo a aclarar el tema, http://androideity.com/2012/06/01/ui-fluidas-y-la-propiedad-weight-en-android/)