# Configurar un layout para que sea responsivo según la pantalla en Android

Tags: android

Quería saber cómo puedo hacer para que los objetos de un `layout` se amolden a los diferentes tamaño de las pantallas de los celulares o tablets.

Por ejemplo:

Si armo el diseño para una pantalla **chica** (Nexus S) se ve bien en esa pantalla, pero si yo emulo en un Samsung s6 se ve todo chiquito.

¿De qué manera puedo adaptar los elementos o qué propiedad se usan para que se adapten a todos los tamaños de pantalla?

Comment: también influye la densidad del dispositivo. Tienes imagenes de lo que   comentas para detallar más tubpregunta

Comment: comenta si esta pregunta te ayuda http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/7150/95

Comment: Elena, yo en la pantalla tengo 2 edittext y 2 botones. no tengo imagenes. no entiendo la pregunta del comentario.  se supone que le tengo que poner la propiedad weight?

Comment: Nicolas, me referia a imagenes de  uno y otro dispositivo para ver con mas detalle tu problema.

Comment: En este enlace se explica como puede afectar la eleccion de DP o SP al tamaño de los textos de tu app. https://www.digitaldot.es/como-evitar-que-cambie-tamano-textos-app/

Comment: Dando tamaño por porcentaje a su padre o al screen.

Answer (score 2):

Android soporta el múltiple diseño de `Layouts` para diferentes tamaños, también puedes hacerlo por medio del uso de pesos sin embargo tus imágenes disminuirán en calidad por la densidad de la pantalla, para que los elementos tomen el tamaño de acuerdo al tamaño del **Screen**.

Android tiene la capacidad de que se incorpore elementos de alta densidad y re dimensionar los a tamaños pequeños pero generaría mayor trabajo de la maquina virtual para realizar este proceso.

Para acomodar tus elementos deacuerdo al tamaño simplemente debes agregar los directorios correspondientes asi como el uso de los **drawables**, ya que una imagen pequeña pierde calidad en una pantalla con mas densidad de resolucion.

Los directorios son :

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout para pantalla normal ("por defecto")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout para pantalla grande
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout para pantalla extra grande
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout para pantalla extragrande en orientacion landscape

res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap para densidad media
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap para densidad grande
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap para densidad extra grande
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap para densidad extra extra grande

res/mipmap-mdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icono para densidad media
res/mipmap-hdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icono para densidad grande
res/mipmap-xhdpi/my_icon.png        // launcher icono para densidad extra grande
res/mipmap-xxhdpi/my_icon.png       // launcher icono para densidad extra extra grande
res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/my_icon.png      // launcher icono para densidad extra extra extra grande
```

Para mayor información tienes la documentacion de Android: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Ya lei la documentación, lo de la carpeta `mipmap-` lo comprendo porque ya lo he utilizado para mi icono pero tengo 2 dudas en cuanto a las otras, 1er duda: al crear las carpetas: `layout`, `layout-large`, `layout-xlarge` y `layout-xlarge-land` significa que creare 4 versiones repetidas de `my_layout.xml` pero diseñadas para diferente tamaño de pantalla? y la 2da duda: que es `graphic.png` hace referencia a un ejemplo de una imagen utilizada en `my_layout`?

Comment: La respuesta para tus dos preguntas es Si

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar la propiedad

```
android:layout_weight="Peso en la pantalla"
```

Donde dice peso en la pantalla tienes que poner un valor absoluto en relación a los otros elementos que tengas.

Ejemplo, si tienes dos imágenes (en una LinearLayout horizontal) y quieres que una sea mayor que otra, pones

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        "/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Fíjate que el layout_width lo dejo a 0 porque no lo voy a usar, me voy a fijar en el **peso en la pantalla**.

Comment: Con este ejemplo el layout se podría ver de la misma forma en cualquier dispositivo?

Answer (score 0):

Yo normalmente uso `LinearLayout` y `RelativeLayout` para maquetear las interfaces, usando valores `dp` y para texto `sp`, asegúrate de que siempre los elementos estén anclados izquierda o derecha o de otro elemento en pantalla, o bien usa la propiedad `layout_weight`.

Comment: podrias proporcionar un ejemplo?